# ggplot count percentage of each bar in bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

i have a bar chart with fill of two levels the y axis is categorical with 0,1. the bar chart shows the 0 count and 1 count now i want to show the each individual percentage of each bar on each bar so that i can see which bar is highest and then which 1 in each bar is higher. but my count is categorical

i want to show percentage of each individual bar as 100% then divided into groups.

ggplot(stackoverflow,aes(x=stackoverflow$person, fill=stackoverflow$success))+facet_wrap(~stackoverflow$city)+geom_bar()

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuzGp.png)

```
   structure(list(data = structure(list(source = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("p", 
"q", "r"), class = "factor"), person = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b", 
"c"), class = "factor"), city = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("x", "y", "z"), class = "factor"), 
    success = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), class = "data.frame"), layers = list(<environment>), scales = <environment>, 
    mapping = structure(list(x = ~stackoverflow$person, fill = ~stackoverflow$success), class = "uneval"), 
    theme = list(), coordinates = <environment>, facet = <environment>, 
    plot_env = <environment>, labels = list(x = "stackoverflow$person", 
        fill = "stackoverflow$success", y = "count", weight = "weight")), class = c("gg", 
"ggplot"))
```

Comment: Could you provide some data? I think I know how to do it, but I need some data for a reply.

Comment: source person city success
p a x 0
p a x 0
q a z 1
q b z 1
q b z 1
q b y 1
i was trying to form graph of person on x axis and then fill= city, count of success on y axis then i want to see in each bar 0 , 1 are there then i want to show that as a percentage

Comment: To properly get your data out so I can view it correctly and work with it, use `dput` function on your dataset. Like `dput(df)` and then copy and paste the result into the question above.

Comment: source person city success( p a x 0 )(p a x 0 )(q a z 1 )(q b z 1 )(q b z 1)( q b y 1)

Comment: how to use dput

Comment: I just edited my previous comment

Comment: can you suggest something now

Comment: Working on it now, but based on your description, I am not sure what your `x` is or `y` is and what percentage you are trying to calculate? Could you clarify? Like for example, `state` and `source` are not anywhere in the `ggplot` code.

Comment: x is person y is sucess which is also a factor i used fill as city so i got a bar graph. now i want in each bar split by percentage of 0 ,1

Comment: i changed the  data for confidential reasons

Comment: I figured, but when you do that, make sure you give a full sample problem.

Comment: i edited the question and data and what i have provided can you help now

Comment: @akash87 can you help

Answer (score 1):

Start with some data aggregation using `tidyverse`:

```
dk %>% 
group_by(person, city, success) %>% 
summarise(counts = n()) %>% 
right_join(dk %>% 
           group_by(city, person) %>% 
           summarise(all_counts= n())) %>% 
mutate(percents = paste0(round(counts/all_counts * 100, 2), "%")) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = person, y = counts, fill = as.factor(success))) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
geom_text(aes(label = percents), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
facet_wrap(~city) + 
coord_flip()
```

So in effect, I first find the count of `success` given `person` and `city` and divide that by the total counts (`all_counts`), which is the total number of `people` given `city`. Then we find the `percents` and then plot it using `ggplot`. Because these are aggregated, we use `geom_bar` with (`stat = "identity"`) and use `geom_text`, which prints the percents (`position_stack(vjust = 0.5)` centers the label). Finally, we `facet` it based on `city`. The `coord_flip()` line flips the x and y axes.

Comment: thanks@akash87, but isnt there a way other than doing the calculations directly through ggplot

Comment: <error>
message: n() should only be called in a data context
class:   `rlang_error`
backtrace:
  1. dplyr::group_by(., person, city, success)
  8. plyr::summarise(., counts = n())
  9. [ base::eval(...) ] with 1 more call
 11. dplyr::n()
 12. dplyr:::from_context("..group_size")
 13. `%||%`(...)

Comment: ok @akassh87 got it can you help me i am not able to copy your code directly it is showing a problem but if i type it is working

Comment: It sounds like a copy/paste error. Also, start the code with `require(tidyverse)` and make sure you have tidyverse installed